# How to skip job in Gitlab pipeline and still run dependencies

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have two jobs in the same stage with a dependency specified via "needs" keyword, for example JobA -> JobB(needs[JobA]).

When I try to skip JobA with a rule (to speedup the build process), JobB throws an 'invalid yaml' error for the "needs" keyword, because the referenced JobA now doesn't exist.

What is the correct syntax/construct to enable such dependency ? Is the use of "rules" in JobA the right approach ?

The simplified version of what I have is:

```
image1:
  stage: build-images
  script:
    - etc...
  rules:
    - changes:
        - values.env

image2:
  stage: build-images
  script:
    - ...
  needs: [image2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`needs:optional:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needsoptional)

```yaml
image1:
  stage: build-images
  script:
    - etc...
  rules:
    - changes:
        - values.env

image2:
  stage: build-images
  script:
    - ...
  needs:
    - job: image1
      optional: true
```